# Why do I get a minus sign when evaluating this triple integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I just tried to compute some triple integrals using *Mathematica* and when I put in this

```
Integrate[x^2 + y^2, 
  {y, -l/2, l/2}, {z, -R, R}, {x, -Sqrt[R^2 - z^2], Sqrt[R^2 - z^2]}]
```

I get a minus sign instead of the (correct) plus sign in the result. On the other hand, when I use

```
Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y, z} ∈ Cylinder[{{0, -l/2, 0}, {0, l/2, 0}}, R]]
```

it works just fine. What is wrong with the first approach?

Comment: The order. Run `Integrate[
 x^2 + y^2, {z, -R, R}, {x, -Sqrt[R^2 - z^2], 
  Sqrt[R^2 - z^2]}, {y, -l/2, l/2}, Assumptions -> R > 0]`; note it's also faster than yours.

Comment: It gets it right in the given order if you add Assumptions -> {l > 0, R > 0} .